# Query dictionary based on a criteria and skip values that are missing

Tags: python, dictionary, removing-whitespace

```
 data = [
        {'firstname': 'Tom ', 'lastname': 'Frank', 'title': 'Mr',
         'education': 'B.Sc'},{'firstname': 'Anne ', 'middlename': 'David', 'lastname': 'Frank', 'title': 'Doctor',
         'education': 'Ph.D'} , {'firstname': 'Ben ', 'lastname': 'William', 'title': 'Mr'}

        ]
```

I want to query the list of dictionaries based on the key 'education'. If the person's detail does not have this key the entire dictionary will be passed over.The desired output is

```
[(' Mr Tom Frank', 'B.Sc'),
 ('Doctor Anne David Frank', 'Ph.D') ]
```

My attempt would have an extra space between Tom and Frank as in `Mr Tom  Frank`  as well as between Anne and David . Here is the actual output

```
[('Mr Tom   Frank', 'B.Sc'), ('Doctor Anne  David Frank', 'Ph.D')]
```

I would like to avoid this if possible. 
Here is the code I have written. I apologize if the code does not seem to be readable enough and I am ready to take any comments.

```
def qualified_applicants(data):
    full_name_education=[ ]
    keys = ['title','firstname','middlename','lastname']
    for record in data:  
        #check to see if 'education' is one of the key 
        if 'education' in record.keys(): 
            full_name=[' '.join([record.get(key,'') for key in keys])]
            # make a tuple of education and full names
            full_name_education.append(tuple(full_name+[record['education']]))
    return full_name_education
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
import re
data = [
    {'firstname': 'Tom ', 'lastname': 'Frank', 'title': 'Mr',
     'education': 'B.Sc'},{'firstname': 'Anne ', 'middlename': 'David', 'lastname': 'Frank', 'title': 'Doctor',
     'education': 'Ph.D'} , {'firstname': 'Ben ', 'lastname': 'William', 'title': 'Mr'}

    ]
new_data = [(re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', ' '.join(re.sub('\s+$', '', i.get(b, '')) for b in ['title', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname'])), i['education']) for i in data if 'education' in i]
```

Output:

```
[('Mr Tom Frank', 'B.Sc'), ('Doctor Anne David Frank', 'Ph.D')]
```

Comment: this is awesome however I need Anne's middle name too. What I mean is Doctor Anne David Frank is the expected output

Comment: thanks for the edit but there are still two spaces after Tom. This will be true for every person with no middle name. This Regex thing is very powerful. I have barely used it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Benyam Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The 'firstname' entries for your data appear to have a trailing blank.  You can trim such leading and trailing white space using the `strip` method of the string returned by `record.get()`.  This would make your list comprehension line be:

```
 full_name = [' '.join([record.get(key,'').strip() for key in keys])]
```

to be tolerant of the extra whitespace.

FWIW, I think you would probably be better off having `full_name` not be a list but a plain string.

Comment: @M Newville thanks for the answer and the comment. After I removed the first name trailing blanks(which was a typo) Doctor Anne David Frank was ok. But not the first output. My code is padding the middle name with a space as per `record.get(key,' ')`.

Comment: you're probably better off building a list of valid, trimmed name parts that would have [title, first, middle, last] or [first, last] if there was no title or middle name, and then do `' '.join(name_parts)`.  Another approach is to join with spaces, then replace double or multiple spaces with single spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The codes seems to be working with the addition of one line of code like so:

```
temp=[' '.join(record.get(key,'') for key in keys)]
full_name=[' '.join(full_name.split() ) for full_name in temp ]
```

The rest of the lines didn't need any change.
This could be verbose but it is working. What is the most pythonic way of achieving the same result?